# How to submit the checkout product details on the database?

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am working on e-commerce website everything is working perfectly. Now I am on the checkout page. Customer first fills the bill details and then place an order.

I am getting the bill details in the database but not getting the order details.

**checkout.php**

```
    <form action="process.php" method="Post">
    <!--bill details field--> 
    //fields 
   <!--end bill details field-->

    <!--shipping detials filed--> 
    //Shipping details   
    <!--end shipping detials filed-->

    <!--order detials are(Session is working perfectly)-->
     if(!empty($_SESSION['product_cart'])):
     foreach($_SESSION['product_cart'] as $key=>$product):
      ?>
     <li>
      <div class="order-list">
      <img src="admin/images/products/<?php echo $product['p_images'];?>"> 
      <?php echo $product['p_brandname'];?>
      <div class="circle-qty"><?php echo $product['quantity'];?></div>
          <span>$<?php echo $product['p_total'];?></span> 

       <input type="hidden" name="o_product_name[]" value="<?php echo $product['p_brandname'];?>">
       <input type="hidden" name="o_product_qty[]" value="<?php echo $product['quantity'];?>">
       <input type="hidden" name="o_product_single_cost[]" value="<?php echo $product['p_currentprice'];?>">
       <input type="hidden" name="o_product_totalcost[]" value="<?php echo $product['p_total'];?>">
                </div>
                 </li>
       <?php $total_amount[]= $product['p_total'];//getting all the product price and assigning to array for total amount?>
            <?php endforeach;?>
       <li class="checkout-total"><div><h2>Total</h2><span>$<?php echo array_sum($total_amount);?></span></div></li>
<?php endif;?>
    </form>
```

I am getting the error

```
Warning: trim() expects parameter 1 to be a string, array given in 

Warning: trim() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in 

Warning: trim() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in 

Warning: trim() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in
```

**Process.php**

```
echo $o_product_name=$conn->real_escape_string(trim($_POST['o_product_name']));
echo $o_product_qty=$conn->real_escape_string(trim($_POST['o_product_qty']));
echo $o_product_single_cost=$conn->real_escape_string(trim($_POST['o_product_single_cost']));
echo $o_product_totalcost=$conn->real_escape_string(trim($_for each_product_totalcost']));
```

I tried to display the value but not working. Even I tried to use implode function but that is also not working.

```
 foreach($o_product_name as $key => $value)
{
   echo $key." has the value". $value;
 }

//second tried
$string=implode(",",$o_product_name);
echo $string;
```

Would you help me out in this?

Comment: Because the parameter given is array and not string as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In process.php ,You can not use array in trim() method

```
 $o_product_name=$_POST['o_product_name'];
 $o_product_qty=$_POST['o_product_qty'];
 $o_product_single_cost=$_POST['o_product_single_cost'];
 $o_product_totalcost=$_POST['o_product_totalcost'];


foreach($o_product_name as $key => $value)
{
   echo $key." has the value". $conn->real_escape_string(trim($value));;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks it's working for me.

Answer (score 0):

`$_POST['o_product_name']` is an Array. You can not pass Array in a trim function. In process.php file you need to loop through the Array of $_POST.

```
foreach($_POST['o_product_name'] as $key=>$value)
{
echo $o_product_name=$conn->real_escape_string(trim($_POST['o_product_name'][$key]));
}
```

And same for the other. Please check for the syntax errors as I have not tested the code but it should work fine.

Thanks.